# При переходе в новую активность пропадает верхняя панель

Tags: android, menu, android-intent, дизайн

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
При нажатии по пункту в меню открывается новая активность, но при этом пропадает верхняя панель.

Код добавления меню и обработка нажатия.

```
Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);
    return true;
}

public void onAboutDev(MenuItem item) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AboutDev.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Код разметки макета, с которым у меня проблема:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/about"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Вот такой вот белый экран с текстом, как исправить?

Comment: Меню для каждой активити нужно устанавливать отдельно

Comment: Если вы используете тему с NoActionBar и в качестве меню используете `Toolbar`, то его нужно указывать в разметке явно, сам он не появится. Посмотрите разметку (и код) первой активити и разберитесь, [как и почему появляется меню](http://androiddocs.ru/toolbar-alternativa-actionbar/) там, потом делайте то же самое для других своих активити.

Comment: @pavlofff мне не нужно меню в следующей активности, мне нужна эта стандартная панель с названием приложения, над которой время, заряд телефона показывается.

Comment: это она и есть, если вы потрудитесь пройти по ссылке выше - можете сами в этом убедится. туда же выводится и меню помимо названия прилодения, если что ...

Answer (score 0):

Сделай лучше фрагменты.

Посмотри туториал: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SpEFzw243T4

Если это не то, что надо и тебе правда нужно "сохранить активити". Скопируй xml с MainActivity на новый активити и тогда меню появится на втором активити

Comment: не совсем то, но за туториал спасибо